# Any issues using useEffect this way?

Tags: reactjs

Is there any potential issues handling componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate with useHooks in this manner?

Two goals here:

1. Use one `useEffect` to handle both `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`
2. No need to pass in the 2nd argument (normally an array with props)

```
const once = useRef(false)
useEffect(() => {

    if(once.current === false){
        once.current = true
        // do things as were in componentDidMount
        return
    }

    // do things as were in componentDidUpdate

    // clean up
    return () => {
        //
    }
}) // <- no need to pass in 2nd argument
```

Comment: This will cause the effect to run on every re-render

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the goal here, to mimic what `componentDidUpdate` used to do, is this gonna be a problem?

Comment: in CDM you usually check props or state and choose what do to, It will be better to add the dependencies to the array, re-renders can still occur if nothing changes. I think you should edit the question and say what you trying to do, it will more easier to provide a better solution

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with it but if any props or state value will change then useEffect will not load on component re-render.

so better to use 2nd argument when this depends on the values change.

```
const once = useRef(false)
useEffect(() => {

    if(once.current === false){
        once.current = true
        // do things as were in componentDidMount
        return
    }

    // do things as were in componentDidUpdate

    // clean up
    return () => {
        //
    }
},[]) // some value as array who will change and this need to be called
```

Comment: I thought useEffect will load on first and every re-render without passing in the 2nd argument?

Answer (score 0):

Yopu should pass an empty array as an argument

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if(once.current === false){
     // do things as were in componentDidMount    
     once.current = true  
  }
  return () => {
      // this area will fired when component unmounts
  }
}, []) // by providing an empty array this useEffect will act like componentDidMount
```

If you want to re-render useEffect on a state change you can add the state to the empty array so it will listen changes in the state and will be executed

```js
const [someStateValue, setSomeStateValue] = useState('')
useEffect(() => {
  ...
}, [someStateValue]) // will be executed if someStateValue changes
```

If you want to combine componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate, I have a solution in my mind that may work

```js
const [val, setVal] = useState('asd')
const [oldVal, setOldVal] = useState('')

useEffect(() => { // componentDidMount
  if(val !== oldVal){ // componentDidUpdate
     // pass val to old val
     setOldVal(val)
     // set new val to new val
     setVal("theNewestVal") 
  }

  return () => { // componentWillUnmount
     ...
  }

}, [val]) // will be executed if someStateValue changes
```

Comment: What you described was actually the first thing I tried, but later figured why not combine the two in one go so that it's less confusing?

Comment: I understand your point, you are trying to make the useEffect combined with didMount and didUpdate at the same time, let me look into it

Comment: @DonKlein did you try the solution?

Comment: Yes, I tried all the suggested approaches above but still favored my original proposal, for the benefit of having all side effects managed in one place, instead of scattered through various clauses.